# Branching library behavior based on 3rd party library existence

Tags: libraries, third-party-libraries

Someone proposed to me this pattern which I have never heard of before and can't find any information on it.

The basic idea is, when building a library for other developers to use; if the developer includes my library along with a 3rd party library the behavior of the API calls to my library changes.

An example:

1. I have a library/API for inserting, getting, updating, deleting on a database.
2. Developer includes a 3rd party database encryption library.
3. My library/API changes to require a "unencrypt(password)" call to be made before inserting, getting, updating, deleting.

Is this a safe practice?  Is there anything else out there like it?  What advantages and disadvantages are there to this pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what you are saying is that you'd like to design your library to have a dependency on a third-party library, and fall back to some default behavior if that third-party library is not available.

I think this is perfectly acceptable as long as it is well-documented.

If you are asking whether it is acceptable for an API call to do two entirely different things, I would say no. The meaning of the API call should not change depending on the presence of another library.

Comment: Agreed. Whether the implementation of the API call uses an internal mechanism or calls out to the 3rd party lib, the API call should honor its contract.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to log whether the internal or external mechanism has been chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. An example I have is; 1) My API has methods for acting on a database. 2) Include a 3rd party library for encrypting databases. 3) Suddenly my API methods for insert, get, update, delete require a "unencrypt(password)" call to be made.  To me this seems similar to the second point you made, where the API does slightly different things.

Comment: In your case I think that your library should be encryption agnostic, and let the developer handle encrypting/decrypting and locking/unlocking. I don't think it would benefit the developer to have this managed internally.